# query last Renewal of licences

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have a Client with Renewal of licences every year. How do I query to get the last year that the clients had renew their licences per section... i tried this code and it worked fine but suddenly it just produce the max year in the section i.e 2014 though there some clients have no renew their licences since 2012...

```
SELECT @last_expired_date = MAX(expired_license_date)
    FROM entrepreneur
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Firm_info
        ON entrepreneur.entre_ID = Firm_info.entre_ID
    RIGHT JOIN Section
        ON Firm_info.Section_ID = Section.Section_id
    RIGHT JOIN license
        ON Firm_info.firm_no = license.firm_no
    RIGHT JOIN license_operations
        ON license.license_serial = license_operations.license_serial
    WHERE Section.Section_id = @section_no
    GROUP BY license.license_serial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Client Name to your `SELECT`  and `GROUP BY` clause, that will give you list of your clients and latest year they have renewed their license.

As a note: use alias for table names in joins. that helps to identify which columns come from which tables. Additionally I avoid using `RIGHT JOIN` because it can make it harder to understand what data you are getting.

Comment: but now i have a column called payed_fine , this column takes the fines payed by clients and make the column fine_amt with value of 0 ,now i'm getting tow rows for the same client one has the value of 0 for column payed_fine and one have the value payed_amt , how to show just the row with payed_amt

Comment: Instead of adding to select and group by list, you should put it into MAX aggregate function `MAX(payed_fine)` column